# Hey! We want some attention for the Super User blog!

Tags: discussion, superuser

We at the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) want our voices to be heard!  We've been operating for 4 months now and have been consistently bringing in nearly 1k views a week.  However this week we had a turn of events:

[image: Views per day for seven day]

In one day we had almost twice the amount of views than what we have in one week, all thanks to Jeff:[image]

So this got me thinking, why not bring more attention to the blog, and in turn Super User and Stack Exchange through automatic tweets from the [@StackExchange](http://twitter.com/#!/StackExchange) twitter account (we would use the official @SuperUser account but it doesn't exist yet).  Now granted, Jeff's 50k+ followers vs @StackExchanges current 2k+ users is a big difference, but currently [I'm mainly](http://twitter.com/#!/SuperKronos) the one [tweeting](http://twitter.com/#!/saved-search/#SuperUserBlog) and I have 29.

This would increase our numbers by a great deal, and I feel that we've earned more recognition.  We have:

- [multiple](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/28/iobit-advanced-systemcare-4/) [product](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/) [reviews](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/03/31/kingston-ssdnow-v100-official-review/)
- [interviews](http://blog.superuser.com/category/interviews/)
- [guides for site improvement](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/)
- even [a podcast!](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/06/ask-different-podcast-1-iphone-location-tracking-dropbox-portal-2/) (courtesy of our friends at Ask Different)
- and many, many more!

With only 1k+ views a week, it's such a shame that our wealth of knowledge and instruction is getting so little views.  Our ultimate goal here is to bring more attention to Super User and Stack Exchange through useful articles that can be referenced within, or point outsiders to Stack Exchange.  And we need your help to do this.  If we could reach a broader audience through automatic tweets of our articles, then perhaps a chain of re-tweets will come raining in and we'll bring the much desired attention to Stack Exchange through the Super User blog.

Comment: TL;DR. WHERE'S YOUR ATTENTION NOW?! HAH!!!

Comment: That's not the result of a tweet, thats the unicorn's horn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the Super User Blog is fantastic. I was incredibly impressed with what you guys (and gals, as applicable) have accomplished there.

But I think you might be thinking of this in the wrong way.

Of course we will do what we can to help*, but to those participating in the blog: you should only be doing so *because you fundamentally enjoy it* and *because it makes you better*. As a writer, as an analyst, as a techie. It is [practicing the fundamentals](http://headrush.typepad.com/creating_passionate_users/2006/03/dont_forget_squ.html).

All that matters is that **you make it awesome**. If the quality is high, participating will be intrinsically rewarding, both to those who pitch in to write for the blog, and those who find the blog. Over time, quality leads to traffic, but you have to be patient. *Really* patient. Turns out, ["overnight" success takes years](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/overnight-success-it-takes-years.html).

You know what? Forget readers. I don't care if anyone reads what I write. I'm writing to satisfy myself first and foremost. If others read it and benefit from it, fantastic -- that's a welcome side effect. If I spent all day worrying about *who* is reading,  *why* they're reading, or if *anyone* is even reading at all, I'd scarcely have time to write.

Remember, [nobody's going to help you](http://sivers.org/up2you).

I say this not to be discouraging, but rather as a call to arms: **it's all up to you.**

<sub><sub>* because we like you! no, not *you*, the other guy!</sub></sub>

Comment: In other words: If you blog it, they will come. I see what you mean and I agree. I, and possibly other bloggers have gotten slightly caught in views and viewers when we need to remember the whole reason why we came to Super User and Stack Exchange in the first place. It's the community that has kept me here and it's ultimately the community who I should in return be blogging for. As we continue to grow in our blogging, so too will that community naturally.  Thanks Jeff.

Comment: and we blogged it, and [they did come](http://cl.ly/0X203D1c3f3U3x0R3q1t), in their hundreds and thousands, for @nhinkle had written a quality post, and the hackers did judge it worthy of #2 on HN, and the hordes of Twitterers did retweet it 105 times, and it did break the nice week-on-week percentage growth figures in my stats table.

Answer (score 8):

Since there are a number of sites with individual blogs now:

- http://blog.serverfault.com
- http://blog.superuser.com
- http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/

We moved the blog link (with dynamic detection and highlighting of new posts) to the top of the page as well as the bottom; it's now mirrored in both places.

[image: blog link with new indicator on superuser.com]

(At least for users who aren't logged in ... we have some space issues on the header.)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the added attention.

Comment: Jeff, I really think that the blogging stuff ought to be integrated into SE. It's frustrating going back to the stone age where you can't vote up comments, and you don't get notified of answers to your comments ;)

Comment: @Benjol, there's been discussing between the team and the blog editors of closer integration some day, but right now, the systems operate separately from each other because of how the blogging platform is set up.

Comment: "... we have some space issues on the header" Could we maybe swap the about link for the blog link when we hit a reputation threshold? After I've used the site long enough, I know what it is about, but don't always know there is a new blog post...