# Why is there a Blog link but only for Guests

Tags: support, status-completed, blog, header

I noticed that a Blog link was added but it seems to only appear if you're not logged in.

What's the deal with that?

[image: Blog Link]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A new feature has been pushed out to address this**. Now, if there has been a new blog post within 24 hours (which triggers a "new" marker on the link), **the blog link will be visible at the top even to logged in users**. This will persist for the full 24 hours, after which the blog link will disappear from the top. It can still be accessed at all times from the footer.

[image: Image of Gaming with the new Blog link even when logged in.]

---

The answer to why the link isn't kept permanently at the top is [found elsewhere on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90208/hey-we-want-some-attention-for-the-super-user-blog/92025#92025), but this question is not really a duplicate of that one. As such, I'll quote Jeff Atwood and add my own emphasis to the portion that addresses this.

> We moved the blog link (with dynamic detection and highlighting of new posts) to the top of the page as well as the bottom; it's now mirrored in both places.
>
> [...]
>
> **(At least for users who aren't logged in ... we have some space issues on the header.)**

Simply put, between our vast badges and stuff and all of the other tools and gadgets you get as a registered user, the top bar is simply too cluttered to stick it up there at all times.

Comment: My initial impression is that this is a very good addition - the [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) has seen far more visitors on days with new posts since the addition of this feature. Making the link visible to logged in users was a good idea indeed. Thanks! :)